# print the first letter of a file in C

Tags: c

Hello guys I am having a problem in printing the first two letter/characters of a .txt file which contains --> "need help". I would like to print the first two letters --> "ne". I tried with ch[], but I couldnt fix, so i changed it back to the part which works:

```
int main() {

    char ch, file_name[2];
    int i;

    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    gets(file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);


    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
        printf("%c",ch);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the `while` loop. How would you exit from it after only 2 characters? Count them then `break;`.

Comment: Just so many other things as well ... I mean what if your `file_name` is more than 1 character ....

Comment: Unrelated, but `char ch, file_name[2];` Is that really what you want?

Comment: `file_name[2]` seems a too small buffer for a file name.

Comment: `file_name[2]` will only allow you to open a file with a 1-character name. That doesn't leave any room for the `.txt` extension.

Comment: `char ch[3];`...`fscanf(fp, "%2s", ch);
printf("%s\n", ch);`

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
char ch[2];
FILE *fp;  
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");      
fread(ch,2,1,fp);
printf("(%c%c) (%2.2s)",ch[0], ch[1],ch); 
}
```

stdout :
(ne) (ne)

Comment: You dont need a null a the end of the string with %2.2s (If a precision is given, no null byte need be present  : man 3 printf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need only the two first letters, but here's how to do it.

```
char file_name[256];
gets(file_name);

int lenght = 0;
strlen(file_name) > 2 ? lenght = 2: lenght = strlen(file_name);

for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    printf("%c", file_name[i]);
```

But an advice that I can give you for strings in C (char arrays) is try to always create a bigger array that you need. It doesn't cost much memory and it's always safer to have more than enough. When you call standards functions like printf(), they will check the null terminated character and this will defines the size of your string.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i came up so far. It prints the first two characters, but then it prints questions marks within a square underneath.
Here is the code:

```
int main() {

char ch[2], file_name[100];
int i;

FILE *fp;

printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
gets(file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name,"r");

if( fp == NULL )
{
  printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
  exit(1);
}

printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

fscanf(fp, "%2s", ch); 
printf("%s\n", ch);




while( ( ch[i] = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
    printf("%c",ch);
}
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ch[2] ... fscanf(fp, "%2s", ch);` will not work.  1) no place for the string null character.  2) `%2s"` will not read spaces.  Still nice attempt.